# Deploying Umbraco Overrides my data

Tags: visual-studio-2012, umbraco, deploying

I am fairly new to Umbraco.  I am using Visual Studio for development and Deployment.  I can deploy my local site to my production server with no problems.  This is ok for now because I am the only one adding content to the site.  When I pass the website to my customer and they start making changes on production, it seems like the next time I deploy the changes are overridden.  The site is setup to use SQL server but I think I might have something messed up.  (In the setup process I selected External DB and put in all the credentials and the Database was created successfully)

Shouldn't the content on the pages be stored in the Database?  At the moment if I log into admin on production and make a simple text change (Change is Deployed and live), then if I go to Visual Studio and Deploy the site, all the changes are reverted back.

Any help would be greatly appreciated... Thanks is advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content of the pages IS stored in the database (as are the document types, datatype configuration and others).  If you use the deploy tool of visual studio make sure you don't redeploy the database, but only the files.
If you are not redeploying the database, you are probably also copying the files (and folder) below:

- /app_data/umbraco.config
- /app_data/temp/ExamineIndexes

These locations contain cached content.  I would never copy the Temp folder or the umbraco.config file, except if you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You probably configured the website for SQL Server CE. This means that the database is stored in a file under `~/App_Data/Umbraco.sdf`. If you overwrite this file, you overwrite the database.

We never use SQL Server CE. We demand SQL Server or SQL Server Express to work with.

Comment: When I setup the site I specified SQL not SQLce.  The file you are speaking of is not on my dev environment or on production.